# Conditionally update SharePoint list column based on another lists's column value

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I am wanting to autofill a field if one of the columns in that list matches another list.

For example, when I create a new item in my purchase orders list and catalog number I enter in my purchase orders list matches the number in the catalog list I want it to auto-update the name of the product in the purchase orders list.

The formula I am wanting to do is below, But I don't know how whats best? POWER AUTOMATE or SHAREPOINT DESIGNER? and I can't figure out how to do it on either of them.

If "Catalogue number" in list PURCHASE ORDERS match "Reference" in the CATALOGUE LIST update Product name in PURCHASE ORDER LIST to match the one in the CATALOGUE LIST

Does anyone know how to do this? any help would be appreciated?

Many thanks
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

We could implement this either using the SharePoint Designer workflow or Power Automate. Let's you are going with the SharePoint Designer workflow. Develop a list level workflow in **PURCHASE ORDERS** list which should trigger on item creation and update.

In the first step of the workflow query (**Call an HTTP web service action**) the **CATALOGUE LIST**, there check for the **"Catalogue number"** Reference field - if that gives the result, means the reference is found, then under the same **If** condition add action **update item** (here in the update item action, need to configure the current list means **PURCHASE ORDERS list and Product name**), then update the **Product name** column in **PURCHASE ORDER** LIST.

The same logic we can implement in the Power Automate also.

Comment: Many thanks for the info, I have gone in to the workflow but I can only see "Get Items from a Dictionary" when typing in the workflow and cannot see it under actions? Would you know why?

Kind Regards Daniel

Comment: You can try with Call an HTTP web service action - this should work

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using **Microsoft Flow** (Power Automate) since it is designed for modern SharePoint.

Create a flow in PURCHASE ORDER list and trigger on **item creation** (*When an item is created or modified* works as well).

Here’s a sample flow for your reference:

[image]

[image]